# What is the distribution of an increment of a Negative Binomial process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, negative-binomial-distribution

If we take a point process with the counting process $N_t$ being Negative Binomial with parameters $r=dt$ and probability $p$ ($0\lt p\lt1$ and $d\gt0$), what is

$$P(N_{t+s} - N_t = k) ?$$